# Ads directing you to other SE sites malfunction

Tags: bug, advertising

Ads on the right sidebar for other community sites seem to malfunction.

I've received an ad for a WorldBuilding topic. First, I copied the link and opened it in private browsing (reflex when doing anything with ads for me). However, the link copied was [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fworldbuilding.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F134530%2Fwhat-is-the-best-design-for-docking-onto-a-rotating-space-station), and that seems to redirect to the home page (even though it's quite clear to me to which page it should direct you).

Then I just clicked the ad, got a *framing is not allowed* popup, and the page reloaded.

Unfortunately, after reloading the ad was gone and I've spent some time trying to repro this with screenshots but have been unable to get that ad again.

Comment: I've gotten the "framing is not allowed" popup when *using the back button on mobile chrome* when browsing Game Dev. I wonder if its related.

Comment: "Unfortunately the ad was gone"?, first time hearing that one