# What exactly is this ad which redirects just to the main homepage with a complicated URL?

Tags: discussion, advertising

So, I was searching some questions tagged with some specific tags when I saw:

[image]

Sorry? What exactly is this? I think that the 1st April day is over! Is there a 14th April Fool Day?

Comment: Could you provide the link that the advert points to?

Comment: Presumably it's a question with a bad title on AU... https://askubuntu.com/q/1133199/761293 it should link to the post directly, though. Where did you click?

Comment: @Catija I was searching for posts tagged with some specific tags - I am now searching through my browser history to find that. When I clicked this 'ad' I was redirected at the Stack Overflow homepage, but.... with a strange and complicated URL. Searching...!

Comment: Those type of Hot Network ads are super buggy. I've posted previous bug reports about odd behavior when clicking on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ads directing you to other SE sites malfunction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378244/ads-directing-you-to-other-se-sites-malfunction). I thought the text is an error message, but I just realized it's the title of the question, thus making this post actually a dupe...